# resize image resolution in visual basic 6

Tags: image, resize, resolution

i'm not expert in visual basic 6
i have problem with resize image resolution to 75x75
when button load pressed image resolution changed to 75x75 then image stretch following size picturebox
the try code like this

```html
Private Sub Command1_Click()
With CommonDialog1
    .Filter = "JPG (*.JPG)|*.JPG"
    .ShowOpen
End With
With Picture1
    .Picture = LoadPicture(CommonDialog1.FileTitle)
    .PaintPicture .Picture, 0, 0, 75, 75
End With
End Sub
```

image size changed to 75x75 but not stretch in picturebox 
then i try code this

```html
Private Sub Command1_Click()
Const W As Integer = 75, H As Integer = 75
With CommonDialog1
    .Filter = ".JPG (*.JPG)|*.JPG"
    .ShowOpen
End With
With Picture1
    .Picture = LoadPicture(CommonDialog1.FileTitle)
    .Width = (W * Screen.TwipsPerPixelX) + .Width - .ScaleX(.ScaleWidth, .ScaleMode, vbTwips)
    .Height = (H * Screen.TwipsPerPixelY) + .Height - .ScaleY(.ScaleHeight, .ScaleMode, vbTwips)
    .AutoRedraw = True
    .Cls
    .PaintPicture .Picture, 0, 0, .ScaleWidth, .ScaleHeight
    .AutoRedraw = False
End With
End Sub
```

image size change following picturebox size when i try save that image the size not changed. 
please help me